# Connect to localhost in Dockerfile build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Redis container launched in `host` network. I can connect to this Redis from my *host* and from other containers launched in `host` network, but I get 'connection refused' error when trying to connect from a build step in my Dockerfile. Am I missing something about networking here?

My `docker-compose.yml` for Redis:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

redis:
  image: redis:latest
  network_mode: "host"
  command: redis-server
  ports:
    - 6379
```

The image I'm trying to build is not in the `docker-compose.yml`, it just needs to use Redis to initialize the app.

Comment: Please share more details, like your `docker-compose.yaml`

Comment: You generally shouldn't be making network connections at all from your Dockerfile, aside from downloading artifacts from HTTP services.  Connecting to cache services or databases doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NicoHaase I've added my docker-compose.yml. However, I think it has no value here, I'm not using docker-compose to build the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze it also seems strange to me, but the app requires assets' precompilation and the precompilation requires app initialization (which requires Redis) and I cannot change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `--network=host` to my `docker build` command solved the problem for me:

```
docker build --network=host -t app:1.0 .
```